# How to enable local caching in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have to call the webapi from angularjs based on cache value. First time i have to call the api and store the input parameters in cache. Next time if same input parameters comes i have to stop calling api from client side. I have tried with cachefactory but value is not retaining after page load. Any suggestion to implement this functionality in client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache) to manage cache by yourself and the 
 [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service let you cache call automatically like:

```
$http.get('api/path', {cache: true} ...
```

Here `api/path` will be your cache key.

Answer (score -1):

You can write cached data to [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to make it persistent to page reloads.

If you prefer a higher level interface - take a look at [angular-cache](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache) module, it supports [localStorage mode](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache#storagemode).

Answer (score -1):

You can store the value in $rootScope but the value won't persist if you reload the page. To persist values after reload, you can store the value in a cookie as well, or in localStorage. Accessing cookie and localStorage content is very easy from Angular code.